# Sending data / payload to the Google Chrome Push Notification with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I'm working on the Google Chrome Push Notification and I'm trying to send the payload to the google chrome worker but, I have no idea how I receive this payload.

I have an API to create and save the notifications in my database and I need send the values through the `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` and receive on the worker.js

This is my worker.js

```
    self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
      var title = 'Yay a message.';
      var body = 'We have received a push message.';
      var icon = '/images/icon-192x192.png';
      var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

      event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
          body: body,
          icon: icon,
          tag: tag
        })
      );
    });
```

And this is how I'm calling the GCM

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyDQjYDxeS9MM0LcJm3oR6B7MU7Ad2x2Vqc" --header  "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{ \"data\":{\"foo\":\"bar\"}, \"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bGqJpCmyCnSHLjY6STaBQEumz3eFY9r-2CHTtbsUMzBttq0crU3nEXzzU9TxNpsYeFmjA27urSaszKtA0WWC3yez1hhneLjbwJqlRdc_Yj1EiqLHluVwHB6V4FNdXdKb_gc_-7rbkYkypI3MtHpEaJbWsj6M5Pgs4nKqQ2R-WNho82mnRU\"]}"
```

I tried to get `event.data` but, this is undefined.

Does anyone have any idea or sugestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve that data, you need to parse "event.data.text()" to a JSON object. I'm guessing something was updated since you tried to get this to work, but it works now. Unlucky!

However, since I made it to this post when searching for a solution myself, others would probably like a working answer. Here it is:

```
// Push message event handler
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

  // If true, the event holds data
  if(event.data){

    // Need to parse to JSON format
    // - Consider event.data.text() the "stringify()"
    //   version of the data
    var payload = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
    // For those of you who love logging
    console.log(payload); 

    var title = payload.data.title;
    var body  = payload.data.body;
    var icon  = './assets/icons/icon.ico'
    var tag   = 'notification-tag';

    // Wait until payload is fetched
    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        tag: tag,
        data: {} // Keeping this here in case I need it later
      })
    );

  } else {
    console.log("Event does not have data...");
  }

}); // End push listener

// Notification Click event
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log("Notification Clicked");
}); // End click listener
```

Personally, I will be creating a "generic" notification in case my data is funky, and will also be using try/catch. I suggest doing the same.

Comment: This is nice. I'm not working with this anymore but, it will be good for another person! Thank you, dude. =]

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately it seems like an [intended behavior](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web):

> A downside to the current implementation of the Push API in Chrome is
>   that you can’t send a payload with a push message. Nope, nothing. The
>   reason for this is that in a future implementation, payload will have
>   to be encrypted on your server before it’s sent to a push messaging
>   endpoint. This way the endpoint, whatever push provider it is, will
>   not be able to easily view the content of the push payload. This also
>   protects against other vulnerabilities like poor validation of HTTPS
>   certificates and man-in-the-middle attacks between your server and the
>   push provider. However, this encryption isn’t supported yet, so in the
>   meantime you’ll need to perform a fetch request to get information
>   needed to populate a notification.

As stated above, the workaround is to contact back your backend after receiving the push and fetch the stored data on the 3rd party server.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I had read it before but, I didn't want believe =l. Is a bad news ...

I'll make a new request on server to get the all information about my notification.

Thank you again

Comment: Indeed. Hope they will support encrypted payloads soon because this feature is almost useless without payload.

Comment: For sure. I'm doing something provisory =l

Comment: I don't understand part of this. I am fine making the fetch call, but how am I supposed to know _what_ to fetch? Does `event` (from the code in the question) have the `multicast_id` or `message_id` from GCM and I'm not seeing it?

Comment: @AndyGaskell If i'm understanding well the idea is that you are always interested in the last event otherwise your server needs to keep some kind of inbox with all enqueued alerts for your device. Either way, you need to implement this on your side. So far the push only signals that "something" has happened.

Comment: @gauchofunky Thanks. After working on it over the weekend you basically need a queue server side that contains your userId (if applicable), subscriptionId, and notification information (title, message, icon). Getting the user context and subscriberId in the service worker's `fetch` was a bit of a pain but I think I'm on the right track now. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndyGaskell So the only solution for now is to send a default notification, identify the user who receives it and take the notification data from your own server (you can have a queue server or the structure you want) but there's no way to send data to Chrome? Even a title or a simple message you can't send? There's some information about when there will be the payload functionality available?

Comment: @eloibm That's correct. Here's the issue on the Chromium project - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=486040

Comment: I appreciate the work the Google guys are doing in this area. Having said that, without a payload of even a few bytes size Chrome messaging is not going to be real useful for the vast majority. From the above cited blog post: "We have implemented the Web exposed API for supporting payloads (Issue 434808), but decided to not ship this because we want to mandate encryption for any received push message that has a payload." IMHO that was a BIG mistake. This is effectively just a technology preview and should be marked as such in docs.

Comment: Seems like it works in Canary with some experimental features turned on. Although, I am still not able to encrypt the payload. So, not working. But I am getting a data object on the target side.

Comment: hello,its been a year now, but there is no update on the payload encryption yet. Even the documentation doesn't specify this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en
Let me know if any of you figure out a way to send additional data to chrome.

Comment: @anurag probably you might be interested on this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=486040

Comment: yeah, i eventually found that link. For now I am sending another call to my server to fetch additional data and displaying that as part of the notification. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 17):

@gauchofunky's answer is correct. With some guidance from the folks on the Chromium dev slack channel and @gauchofunky I was able to piece something together. Here's how to work around the current limitations; hopefully my answer becomes obsolete soon!

First figure out how you're going to persist notifications on your backend. I'm using Node/Express and MongoDB with Mongoose and my schema looks like this:

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  _user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  subscriptionId: String,
  title: String,
  body: String,
  sent: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

Be sure to add an icon if you'd like to alter the icon. I use the same icon every time so mine's hardcoded in the service worker.

Figuring out the correct REST web service took some thought. GET seemed like an easy choice but the call to get a notification causes side effects, so GET is out. I ended up going with a `POST` to `/api/notifications` with a body of `{subscriptionId: <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>}`. Within the method we basically perform a dequeue:

```
var subscriptionId = req.body.subscriptionId;

Notification
.findOne({_user: req.user, subscriptionId: subscriptionId, sent: false})
.exec(function(err, notification) {
  if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  notification.sent = true;
  notification.save(function(err) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.status(201).json(notification);
  });
});
```

In the service worker we need to for sure get the subscription before we make the `fetch`.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
      fetch('/api/notifications/', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
      })
      .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
      .then(function(data) {
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
          body: data.body,
          icon: 'favicon-196x196.png'
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
      });
    })
  );
});
```

It's also worth noting that the subscription object changed from Chrome 43 to Chrome 45. In Chrome 45 the `subscriptionId` property was removed, just something to look out for - this code was written to work with Chrome 43.

I wanted to make authenticated calls to my backend so I needed to figure out how to get the JWT from my Angular application to my service worker. I ended up using `postMessage`. Here's what I do after registering the service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope:'./'}).then(function(reg) {
  var messenger = reg.installing || navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
  messenger.postMessage({token: $localStorage.token});
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err');
  console.log(err);
});
```

In the service worker listen for the message:

```
self.onmessage.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  self.token = event.data.token;
});
```

Strangely enough, that listener works in Chrome 43 but not Chrome 45. Chrome 45 works with a handler like this:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  self.token = event.data.token;
});
```

Right now push notifications take quite a bit of work to get something useful going - I'm really looking forward to payloads!

Comment: Thanks Andy this info was really helpful

Answer (score 14):

Actually, payload should be implemented in Chrome 50 (release date - April 19, 2016). In Chrome 50 (and in the current version of Firefox on desktop) you can send some arbitrary data along with the push so that the client can avoid making the extra request. All payload data must be encrypted.

Here is the the encryption details from developer : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en

Comment: please, extend your answer, link is not enough.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem. Newer versions of firefox and chrome( version 50+) support payload transferring. 
The dev docs [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption?hl=en) details the implementation on how this works. An important thing to note is that google GCM or possibly client/chome (I dont know which one) will actually ignore the payload entirely if it is not encrypted.

[This](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_service-worker_doc.html) website has both client/server implementations of how to do the push and retrieval through service workers. The push library that examples use is merely a [wrapper around a normal REST call](https://github.com/marco-c/web-push)

***service worker*** example implementation:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
var payload = event.data ? event.data.text() : 'no payload';

event.waitUntil(
   self.registration.showNotification('ServiceWorker Cookbook', {
     body: payload,
   })
 );
});
```

***Server*** example implementation:

```
var webPush = require('web-push');

webPush.setGCMAPIKey(process.env.GCM_API_KEY);

module.exports = function(app, route) {
 app.post(route + 'register', function(req, res) {
 res.sendStatus(201);
});

app.post(route + 'sendNotification', function(req, res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   webPush.sendNotification(req.body.endpoint, {
     TTL: req.body.ttl,
     payload: req.body.payload,
     userPublicKey: req.body.key,
     userAuth: req.body.authSecret,
   }).then(function() {
    res.sendStatus(201);
   });
  }, req.body.delay * 1000);
 });
};
```

***Client side javascript*** implementation example of printing out the the required fields.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js')
.then(function(registration) {

    return registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
        .then(function(subscription) {
            if (subscription) {
                return subscription;
            }
            return registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true
            });
        });
}).then(function(subscription) {
    var rawKey = subscription.getKey ? subscription.getKey('p256dh') : '';
    key = rawKey ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(rawKey))) : '';
    var rawAuthSecret = subscription.getKey ? subscription.getKey('auth') : '';
    authSecret = rawAuthSecret ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(rawAuthSecret))) : '';
    endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
    console.log("Endpoint: " + endpoint);
    console.log("Key: " + key);
    console.log("AuthSecret: " + authSecret);
});
```

Comment: Yes - it should. (Although its been a while since Ive tried it). It worked when I first wrote the post :)

Comment: Actually i am trying for push notification in chrome, but its not working. The same code is working fine in firefox. So just wanted to know could you help with this to solve my issue? I have my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042783/push-notification-is-not-being-sent-to-chromedesktop-level/40043690#40043690

I have placed console in webpush.sendNotification() promise the console vlaue has never come, if it is run in chrome. But in firefox i can see the console value.

Comment: upgrade your chrome. It has to be version 50+.

Comment: Chrome Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to achieve this:

**In the browser:**

You need to get the `subscription` object and save it, so your server has access to it: [Read more about it](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/push-messaging-and-notifications)

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(serviceWorkerRegistration => {
            serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
              .then(subscription => {
                  //save subscription.toJSON() object to your server
    })});
```

**In the server:**

install [web-push npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push)

And send a web push like this:

```
    const webpush = require('web-push');


    setImmediate(async () => {

      const params = {
        payload: {title: 'Hey', body: 'Hello World'}
      };
      //this is the subscription object you should get in the browser. This is a demo of how it should look like
      const subscription = {"endpoint":"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/deC24xZL8z4:APA91bE9ZWs2KvLdo71NGYvBHGX6ZO4FFIQCppMsZhiTXtM1S2SlAqoOPNxzLlPye4ieL2ulzzSvPue-dGFBszDcFbSkfb_VhleiJgXRA8UwgLn5Z20_77WroZ1LofWQ22g6bpIGmg2JwYAqjeca_gzrZi3XUpcWHfw","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BG55fZ3zZq7Cd20vVouPXeVic9-3pa7RhcR5g3kRb13MyJyghTY86IO_IToVKdBmk_2kA9znmbqvd0-o8U1FfA3M","auth":"1gNTE1wddcuF3FUPryGTZOA"}};

      if (subscription.keys) {
        params.userPublicKey = subscription.keys.p256dh;
        params.userAuth      = subscription.keys.auth;
      }

// this key you should take from firebase console for example
// settings -> cloud messaging -> Server key     
webpush.setGCMAPIKey('AAAASwYmslc:APfA91bGy3tdKvuq90eOvz4AoUm6uPtbqZktZ9dAnElrlH4gglUiuvereTJJWxz8_dANEQciX9legijnJrxvlapI84bno4icD2D0cdVX3_XBOuW3aWrpoqsoxLDTdth86CjkDD4JhqRzxV7RrDXQZd_sZAOpC6f32nbA');

      try {
        const r = await webpush.sendNotification(subscription, JSON.stringify(params));
        console.log(r);
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    });
```