# Unable to retrieve GCM push event data using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, browser, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing website using GCM . 
i am already testing service worker and gcm  on push event. 
but why , while i am send push ( from server using php) to all client (iOS,Android,and Browser) push listener is works great . 
on mobile , data which i send from server received perfectly,but on browser not(Chrome latest version) .when i simulate push from service worker Push event > data has object.when i send notification from server Push Event > data always null . 
please somebody advantage with gcm help me

Comment: Have you declared the gcm permission in manifest.json? [Implementing GCM Client on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#top_of_page) might really help. :)

Comment: yes,i had declared permission.
`"permissions": [
    "gcm","storage","pushMessaging","notifications"
   ]`

Comment: I have a same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data / payload to the Google Chrome Push Notification with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335749/sending-data-payload-to-the-google-chrome-push-notification-with-javascript)