# Why is my Service Worker's push event data/payload null?

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-messaging, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made multiple attempts to get desktop notifications working in Chrome, but I have not found a single source of documentation that covers a step by step procedure to get desktop notifications to work correctly. Each resource I have come across is either outdated or inconsistent with others.

The problem I am facing is: once the Service Worker receives the `push` event,

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(
            event.data.title,
            {
                body: event.data.body,
                icon: event.data.icon,
                tag: event.data.tag
            }));
});
```

`event.data` is null. I expect it to have data that I am sending as JSON in a POST request like this:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=<FCM Server Key here>

{
    "data": {
        "title": "Foo",
        "body": "Bar"
    },
    "to": "<recipient ID here>"
}
```

The weird thing is the registration script gets a "subscription endpoint" that looks like `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/<recipient ID here>`, but I cannot get the POST to go through unless I follow other examples on the web that say to put the recipient ID as the `to` field in the JSON I am sending.

Of all the examples I have come across, there are multiple URLs that POST calls are being made to:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

I have tried all three, with each attempt having the recipient at the end of the API address (like `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/<recipient ID here>` and alternatively in the JSON body. My goal is to get **Foo** and **Bar** from the data I am sending into the `self.registration.showNotification(` method of the service worker.

Why is `event.data` null? Can anyone point me to a *complete* guide from start to finish that favors FCM over GCM? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi there.. found the answer?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure this out?

Comment: hi there, found the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the following statement from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web),

> A downside to the current implementation of the Push API in Chrome is that you can't send any data with a push message. Nope, nothing. The reason for this is that in a future implementation, payload data will have to be encrypted on your server before it's sent to a push messaging endpoint. This way the endpoint, whatever push provider it is, will not be able to easily view the content of the push message. This also protects against other vulnerabilities like poor validation of HTTPS certificates and man-in-the-middle attacks between your server and the push provider. However, this encryption isn't supported yet, so in the meantime you'll need to perform a fetch to get information needed to populate a notification.

Reading further, you may want to try using `fetch()` to get data from an API, convert the response to an object and use it to populate notification. This same method was also used in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335749/sending-data-payload-to-the-google-chrome-push-notification-with-javascript).

In addition to that, you may want to also check the response of @Indici Indici in the [thread](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web#what_happens_if_i_send_10_push_messages_but_only_want_the_device_to_receive_one) wherein he stated that push event does not contain data values; instead it contains different events which contains information(s). Here is the sample code that was provided as a possible workaround to receive notification in Firebase service-worker in "push" event:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    const dataText = event.data.text();
    notificationTitle = 'Custom Notification';
    notificationOptions.body = 'Message: ' + `${dataText}`;
    var title = event.data.notification.title;
    var message = event.data.notification.message;
    var icon = event.data.notification.icon;
    var notificationTag = event.data.notification.tag;﻿
  }
}﻿
```

Comment: what if the data is not from any API but just firebase send request body? and @Conner Harkness mentioned `data` is null then why he will need `if (event.data)` condition?

Answer (score 1):

For receive data need:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
// jsonData -> here is you data 
const options = {
    body: 'set you body',
    icon: 'img/apple-icon-120x120.png',
    badge: 'img/apple-icon-120x120.png'
};
event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(jsonData.data.title, options)); 
});
```