# Chorme Web Push Notification with payload

Tags: php, web, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  var jsonObj = event.data.json();
}
```

I have written chrome web push notification, but `event.data` is always null.

Currently I am using GCMPushMessage library, I think I need php curl for sending notification. Can anybody help me to send web push notification with payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2015 , this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337242/5995040) stated, this is an intended behavior.

> A downside to the current implementation of the Push API in Chrome is that you can't send any data with a push message. Nope, nothing. The reason for this is that in a future implementation, payload data will have to be encrypted on your server before it's sent to a push messaging endpoint. This way the endpoint, whatever push provider it is, will not be able to easily view the content of the push message. This also protects against other vulnerabilities like poor validation of HTTPS certificates and man-in-the-middle attacks between your server and the push provider. However, this encryption isn't supported yet, so in the **meantime you'll need to perform a fetch to get information needed to populate a notification**.

As provided by the document you have to fetch the information then populate it in the notification.

An update was released March 2016 named : [Web Push Payload Encryption](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption)

> Prior to Chrome 50, push messages could not contain any payload data. When the 'push' event fired in your service worker, all you knew was that the server was trying to tell you something, but not what it might be. You then had to make a follow up request to the server and obtain the details of the notification to show, which might fail in poor network conditions.
>
> Now in Chrome 50 (and in the current version of Firefox on desktop) you can send some arbitrary data along with the push so that the client can avoid making the extra request. However, with great power comes great responsibility, so all payload data must be encrypted.

Ensure you've followed the implementation needed for applying payload in web push for Chrome. Like some Client-side changes and Server-side changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! i have setup this using fetch() method with TTL:3600, So now Its working fantastic...